# Expo publish command getting stuck after tunnel connected stage

Tags: gitlab, expo, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab-ci to publish react native app using expo cli but the pipeline gets stuck at the tunnel connected stage. How do I fix this issue ?

```
cache:
  paths:
   - node_modules/
stages:
  - deploy
before_script:
  - npm ci
expo-deployments:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "EXPO_USERNAME=""$EXPO_USERNAME" >> .env
    - echo "EXPO_PASSWORD=""$EXPO_PASSWORD" >> .env
    - npx expo login -u "$EXPO_USERNAME" -p "$EXPO_PASSWORD"
    - cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
    - echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sysctl -p
    - npx expo publish --non-interactive
```

Here is the pipeline screenshot.
[image]

Not really sure what might be the issue. Tried to search but didn't find any concrete solution specific to this problem.